# WPF TreeView does not display items from observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a TreeView that I'm binding to an observable collection, which has one observable collections inside of it.

I have the following classes:

the base class:

```
public class BaseObject : BindableBase, IBaseObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and 2 other class for directory and files which inherit from this BaseObject. Right now the difference between File and Directory class is the collection:

```
    public ObservableCollection<BaseObject> DirectoryItems
    {
        get => _directoryItems;
        set
        {
            _directoryItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

In my view model I add files and directories to fill the observable collection, but the problem is that the TreeView is empty.
The following is the xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate 
        x:Key="ProjectExplorerFileTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
        x:Key="ProjectExplorerFolderTemplate"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProjectExplorerFileTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DirectoryItems}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Margin="10">
    <TreeView 
        Name="ProjectExplorerTreeView"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProjectExplorerFolderTemplate}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectExplorerNodes}" />
</Grid>
```

I am not sure where I am doing something wrong.
In the observable collection I have all data that I need.
The problem it is in the xaml?

EDIT
ProjectExplorerNodes is the observable collections where I add the files and directories from root path, in view model.

```
    public ObservableCollection<BaseObject> ProjectExplorerNodes
    {
        get => _projectExplorerNodes;
        set
        {
            _projectExplorerNodes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is ProjectExplorerNodes?

Comment: @Clemens ProjectExplorerNodes is the observable collections where I add the files and directories from root path, in view model

Comment: You mean ProjectExplorerNodes? Show the declaration and also how you set the view's DataContext.

Comment: DataContext="{Binding Source=ProjectExplorerViewModel}"
this is maybe what you asked?

Comment: In case `ProjectExplorerViewModel` is a property of the main view model, set `DataContext="{Binding Path=ProjectExplorerViewModel}"`, not Source.

Comment: no, there is my mistake, it was the name, it is not a property

Comment: yeah there was my mistake how I set datacontext